# Query returns more rows

Tags: sql

I have two tables. product_type listing name of products with product id. There are 5 product types which have same product id (1) as they are shared along with 4 other product types with unique product ids (2 to 9). Other table is product. It has the list of customer ids along with what product template id associated with it.

I want to get a list of products which are being used by customer. But I am getting a list with duplicate product rows if there are two customers using the same product. I just want to get a unique list of products being used by all the customers.

Product Table

```
Product  Product_id
AML        1
EDU        1
EXM        1
JEXM       2
JFSA       3
```

Customer Table

```
Customer_id   Product_id
112            1
113            2
114            1
115            3
116            4
117            2
```

The query:

```
SELECT CTE.ProductType, CTE.PRODUCT_ID, DECODE(CT.PRODUCT_ID,NULL,0,1) AS HasCustomer
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      LISTAGG(pt.product_type, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY pt.product_type) as ProductType, 
      pt.PRODUCT_ID
      FROM product_type pt          
      group by pt.PRODUCT_ID) CTE
 JOIN CUSTOMER CT ON CT.PRODUCT_ID = CTE.PRODUCT_ID;
```

> Blockquote

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: It returns JEXM two times, same with AML

Comment: I asked about your _expected_ output, not what you are currently getting (but, showing us both would be helpful).

Comment: As I have mentioned in my original question, I need to get a list of products which are being used by the customers. For example, Product Product_id Has Customer JFSA 3 0, JEXM 2 1. Instead of this, it returns: JEXM 2 1, JEXM 2 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT c.customer_id,
       LISTAGG(p.product, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY p.product) as products
FROM customers c JOIN
     products p
     ON c.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID       
GROUP BY c.customer_id;
```

For each customer, this will give the list of products for the customer.

I based this on your sample data.  I don't see the relationship between your query and the sample data.

EDIT:

If you want all products used by any customer, then simply do:

```
select distinct c.product_id
from customers c;
```

Comment: I need a unique list of products which are being used so far. I don't need any information of customer. With the above query, it gives me a list of customer ids with the product they use. So if there are two customers using the same product, it gives me the product two times. Column with Product is ProductType. It was misspelled.